# youtube videos won't fullscreen properly on dual monitor setup

Tags: flash, youtube, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make YouTube fullscreen actually fullscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36820/how-to-make-youtube-fullscreen-actually-fullscreen)

When I try to make youtube videos fullscreen, they become boxed within the middle of the screen, with the control bar not on the bottom, [like so](https://i.imgur.com/dZQU7.png).

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/6enan.png) you can see what it looks like including my second monitor (which is smaller, hence the black bar at the bottom).

1st monitor = 1600x900

2nd monitor = 1024x768

This occurs on various installations of ubuntu I've had, across multiple releases. No combination of open source and proprietary video and flash drivers seems to fix it. I'm currently using the fglrx ati drivers and the latest flash version. This seems to only occur with youtube videos - I can't remember any other sites that cause the same problem.

Any fixes or workarounds?

Thanks