# Again problem with youtube fullscreen on dual monitors

Tags: flash, youtube, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

My problem is same (I think) to [How to make YouTube fullscreen actually fullscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36820/how-to-make-youtube-fullscreen-actually-fullscreen) and I tried to enable\disable HTML 5, but it doesn't fix the problem. What should I do?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I don't know how to fix that, I've been searching for 2 hours, but the problem is still unsolved :(

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: "Possible Duplicate: How do I fix Flash issues?" Didn't you see that that is completely different problem and none of those solutions didn't solve my problem!